# How to handle button click and how to get the content of input text in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I need to get the data entered in the input text. Using document.getElementById, but displays the error: ReferenceError: document is not defined.
That is, I need to click on the button i get all the data that the user entered.
.........................................................................
.........................................................................
.........................................................................
.........................................................................
.........................................................................
.........................................................................

```
const express = require('express');

const router = express.Router();

const Cookies = require('cookies');

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8');
  //   console.log(res.headers(['cookie']));
  //   res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', 'TestHeader=HeaderValue');
  const cookies = new Cookies(req, res);
  if (req.url === '/favicon.ico') {
    res.end();
    return;
  }
  cookies.set('admin', 'true');
  console.log(cookies.get('node'));
  res.end(`
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
      <head>
          <meta charset="UTF-8">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
          <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
          <title>Document</title>
          <script src="signUp.js" defer></script>
      </head>
      <body>
          <h1>Sign Up Form</h1>
          <form method="POST" action="/sign-up" autocomplete="off">
              <div>
                  <label for="name">Name</label>
                  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required autocomplete="off">
              </div>

              <div>
                  <label for="email">Email</label>
                  <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required autocomplete="off">
              </div>

              <div>
                  <label for="password">Password</label>
                  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" required autocomplete="off">
              </div>

              <div>
                  <label for="password_confirmation">Password again</label>
                  <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" id="password_confirmation" required autocomplete="off">
              </div>

              <button id="sign_up_btn">Sign Up</button>

          </form>
          <a href="/sign-in">Sign In</a>
      </body>
  </html>
  `);

  const userName = document.getElementById('name');
  const userEmail = document.getElementById('email');
  const userPassword = document.getElementById('password');

  const userData = [userName, userEmail, userPassword];
  for (let i = 0; i < userData.length; i += 1) {
    console.log(userData[i]);
  }
});
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8');
  res.statusCode = 501;
  res.end('Not implemented yet!...');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

please place the script before `</body>`, or in `window.onload` callback function. Because document object is not created when you call `document.getElementById`

Answer (score 0):

You've edited your question so allow me to edit my answer:

Your implementation here is incorrect. You are using Express to serve a webpage with a form. In order to evaluate the values of the form, you'll need to decide if you want to do that on the client side or the server side.

Your form looks like a login form, so you'll want to process this on the server side.

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Cookies = require('cookies');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

router.use(bodyParser.json());
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8');
    //   console.log(res.headers(['cookie']));
    //   res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', 'TestHeader=HeaderValue');
    const cookies = new Cookies(req, res);
    if (req.url === '/favicon.ico') {
        res.end();
        return;
    }
    cookies.set('admin', 'true');
    console.log(cookies.get('node'));
    res.end(`
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
      <head>
          <meta charset="UTF-8">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
          <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
          <title>Document</title>
          <script src="signUp.js" defer></script>
      </head>
      <body>
          <h1>Sign Up Form</h1>
          <form method="POST" action="/sign-up" autocomplete="off">
              <div>
                  <label for="name">Name</label>
                  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required autocomplete="off">
              </div>

              <div>
                  <label for="email">Email</label>
                  <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required autocomplete="off">
              </div>

              <div>
                  <label for="password">Password</label>
                  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" required autocomplete="off">
              </div>

              <div>
                  <label for="password_confirmation">Password again</label>
                  <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" id="password_confirmation" required autocomplete="off">
              </div>

              <button id="sign_up_btn">Sign Up</button>

          </form>
          <a href="/sign-in">Sign In</a>
      </body>
  </html>
  `);

    router.post('/sign-up', (req, res) => {
        const { name, email, password } = req.body;

        // do stuff with name, email, password

    });
});
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8');
    res.statusCode = 501;
    res.end('Not implemented yet!...');
});

module.exports = router;
```

For client side form processing, you could do something like this:

HTML

```
<form action="#" onsubmit="handleSubmit(this)">
  <input type="text" name="foo" value="bar" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Javascript

```
function handleSubmit(e) {
  console.log(e.foo.value)
}
```

[Example](https://codepen.io/majestic84/pen/gObPOxG)